# Scanning All Addresses in ProcessMemory

Tags: windows, memory-management

I'm pretty new to C++, and I decided to make a simple "scanner" that will scan all the addresses of a process and print the values. I'm starting with the calculator appliaction, and this is my code

Edit: I changed my code to this

```
int main()
{
    HWND h_wnd = FindWindow("Calculator", 0);
    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(h_wnd, &pid);
    HANDLE h_calc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
    int someValue;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        void *address = (void*)i;
         ReadProcessMemory(h_calc, address, &someValue, 4, 0);
    cout << "Address: " << address << " " << someValue << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And this is what I get for every address

```
Address: 000003DB -858993460
Address: 000003DC -858993460
Address: 000003DD -858993460
Address: 000003DE -858993460
Address: 000003DF -858993460
Address: 000003E0 -858993460
Address: 000003E1 -858993460
Address: 000003E2 -858993460
Address: 000003E3 -858993460
Address: 000003E4 -858993460
Address: 000003E5 -858993460
Address: 000003E6 -858993460
Address: 000003E7 -858993460
```

What am I doing wrong?

but what I want it to do, is find ALL the addresses, and print out their values. I realize this could be a lot to print out, but I just want to see it for the results.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First, how to do this is OS specific, and in most OS implemntations you will not be allowed to see the memory space of an other process (a security risk if you could do so) -- hence, you may want to tag your questions with the specific OS you are using.


Thrid, you may want to find something a little less OS specific to try your C++ skills :-)

Comment: @Soren Thanks Soren, it's Windows 7, how can It not be possible though? There are programs like CheatEngine that do this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "print out their values"?  What values?  The raw bytes in memory?  Memory isn't tagged, so given an arbitrary address, you can't know whether the data at that address is an integer of some kind or a floating point value or something else.

Comment: @James McNellis I understand what you're saying, but as long as I can see some CHANGE in all the data, then I will figure out specific searching from there (which types to search for)

Comment: With respect to the edit, the problem is that `ReadProcessMemory` will fail and return `FALSE` if there is no accessible memory at the requested address.  You need to check for this failure.  Remember that most processes only use a very small part of their available address space.

Comment: @James McNellis Thanks, I'll take a look. And am I at least on the right track? By the way, another line I added isn't working `if(someValue == 858993460) continue;` It skips past this even when the value does equal that.

Comment: @Austin -- Maybe it is possible in Windows7 -- I have never had much faith in Microsoft producing secure OS software anyway -- however SSL and many other programs which handle secrets could easily be compromised if another un-priviledge process can read its memory.   However if yo run it as a privileged process (equivalent to root on linux) then the game is different  

Have you tried to check the return value of ReadProcessMemory to see if it returns any error values?

Comment: It's not `858993460`, it's `-858993460`, which is `0xcccccccc`.  The debug runtime fills the stack with `0xcc` bytes before your program gets access to it to help you find where you are using an uninitialized variable.  You don't want to check `if (someValue == /* something */)`, check `if (!ReadProcessMemory(...))`.

Comment: @James McNellis I added this just now  `if(!ReadProcessMemory(h_calc, address, &someValue, 4, 0)) {
    cout << "Error! False!" << endl;
    continue;` and it returns error every single address. What could be wrong?`

Comment: From Windows manual it is clear that you can only 'OpenProcess' if the process is in debug mode -- You need to check the return value of that call as well.

Comment: @Soren:  No, typically a process cannot read memory owned by another process; to do this the reading process needs to have specific permission to do so.

Comment: @Austin:  Well, you're only checking the first 1,000 addresses... why do you think one of those will be usable?

Comment: @James McNellis I added GetLastError() and its printing out 6, and how do I make it so my process has permission to read memory?

Comment: While this started as a C++ question, then this has really nothing to do with C++, and probably should be moved to ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

Instead of,

```
int addr = 0xFFFFFF;
```

Can't you choose,

```
void *addr = 0;
```

For address purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really doing anything wrong, it's just that your results aren't that interesting (data-wise... not meant to sound insulting).

The value `-858993460` is just `0xcccccccc`, which Microsoft compilers use to detect memory overruns.  Often times memory outside of your allocated values is initialized to a special value so that if you get it, you'll know right away that you're accessing some place that you didn't mean to (or aren't supposed to).  Another pattern that many folks use is `0xDEADBEEF`, just because it's an odd value that spells something out when printed in hex.

Answer (score 1):

OpenProcess and ReadProcessMemeory is only available for processes in debug mode:

See manual here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx for more info

Check the return values of those two calls and see what you get.

Comment: Hey I looked at this, and I changed some code `HANDLE h_calc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
 if(h_calc == NULL) {
  cout << "Handle is null!";
  system("pause");
  return 0;
 }` and handle keeps returning null no matter what permissions I change it to.

Comment: I think the process you are scanning have to agree to be in debug mode before the system would allow you to do this... otherwise security would be compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Since no process use their entire [virtual adress space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), what you first have to do is determine which [pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_page) can and can't be read.

Windows provides the [VirtualQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366907.aspx) function which allows you to scan a processe's memory in order to get the state of an address range. So what you'll be doing is calling this function in a loop and print the content of the ranges with the `MEM_COMMIT` attribute. The details are left out as homework :)

You may also find the [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631%28VS.85%29.aspx) function useful. It enumerates every executables that are loaded in the process along with their base address. Again, details are left out as homework.

Also, if you only want to use the [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, then I believe you only need to pass [`PROCESS_VM_READ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and maybe `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` to OpenProcess. This should avoid having to set the target process in debug mode as Soren mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is arising because you are casting `i` to an address, but with i being less than 1kb, its never going to be in the processes address space. What you need to do is get the HANDLE/HMODULE for the process, then get the base process memory address from that(depending on the memory you want to scan, this can be gotten from the PE, for code, data, text sections etc, or via psapi for reserved system memory), then from you do `void* address = (void*)((UINT_PTR)base + i);`. it would also be a good idea to bound i to the size of the memory section, optionally rounded to a page boundery.